# DLSQL table error getting too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written a DLSQL Table which draws the parameters from an excel file. I am getting errors such as too many values or the table does not process. The order of tables is not correct on the table as you can see the foreign keys in some of the first tables corrspond to the table below.

Here is the Excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzum6VJXi9lUdzJYa0tZbHhpbUk/view?usp=sharing

```
    BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table DEPARTMENT cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table EMPLOYEE cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table DEPENDENT cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table DEPT_LOCATION cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table LOCATION cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table STAGING_DEPLOCATION cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table PROJECT cascade constraint';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table WORKS_ON cascade constraint';


EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
END;
/


CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(DEPT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
DEPARTMENTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_SSN NUMBER(9,0) NULL,
MANAGER_STARTDATE DATE NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DEPT_NO));

/

/
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(SSN NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
MI VARCHAR2(5) NULL, 
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NULL,
CITY VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
STATE VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
ZIP VARCHAR2(5) NULL,
SEX VARCHAR2(1) NULL,
SALARY NUMBER(15,0) NULL,
SUPERVISOR_SSN NUMBER(9) NULL,
DEPT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO));
/



CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT
(DEPENDENT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
SSN NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
DOB DATE NULL,
SEX VARCHAR2(1) NULL,
RELATIONSHIP VARCHAR2(1) NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (DEPENDENT_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(SSN) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN));

/

CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATION
(DEPT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
LOCATION_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
ISACTIVE CHAR(10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO)
FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION_NO) REFERENCES LOCATION(LOCATION_NO));

/

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(SSN NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
MI VARCHAR2(5) NULL, 
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NULL,
CITY VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
STATE VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
ZIP VARCHAR2(5) NULL,
SEX VARCHAR2(1) NULL,
SALARY NUMBER(15,0) NULL,
SUPERVISOR_SSN NUMBER(9) NULL,
DEPT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO));

/

CREATE TABLE LOCATION
(LOCATION_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
LOCATION VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LOCATION_NO));

/
CREATE TABLE STAGING_DEPLOCATION(
LOCATION VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
ISACTIVE CHAR(10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO)
FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION_NO) REFERENCES LOCATION(LOCATION_NO));
/

CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PROJECT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
DEPT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
LOCATION_NO NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
PROJECTNAME VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION_NO) REFERENCES LOCATION(LOCATION_NO));

/

CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON
(SSN NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_NO NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
HOURS NUMBER(15,0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SSN, PROJECT_NO));

create sequence dependent_seq 
start with 1
increment by 1
nocache 
nocycle;


SET DEFINE OFF;


INSERT  INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPT_NO, DEPARTMENTNAME, MANAGER_SSN, MANAGER_STARTDATE) VALUES ('1', 'headquarters', '888665555', '1971-06-19');
INSERT  INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPT_NO, DEPARTMENTNAME, MANAGER_SSN, MANAGER_STARTDATE) VALUES ('2', 'administration', '987987987', '1985-01-01');
INSERT  INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPT_NO, DEPARTMENTNAME, MANAGER_SSN, MANAGER_STARTDATE) VALUES ('3', 'research', '333445555', '1978-05-22');

INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('123456789', 'Roberto', 'B', 'Tamburello', '1955-01-09', '731 Fondren', 'Houston', 'TX', '11233'. 'M', '30000', '333445555', '5');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('333445555', 'David', 'T', 'Bradley', '1945-12-08', '38 Voss', 'Houston', 'TX', '11233', 'M', '40000', '888665555', '5');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('453453453', 'Mary', 'A', 'Dempsey', '1962-07-31', '5631 Rice', 'Houston', 'TX', '11233', 'F', '25000', '333445555', '5');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('666884444', 'Ramesh', 'K', 'Narayan', '1952-08-15', '975 Fire Oak', 'Humble', 'TX', '11232', 'M', '38000', '333445555', '5');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('888665555', 'James', 'E', 'Borg', '1991-11-10', '450 Stone', 'Houston', 'TX', '11233', 'M', '55000', '', '1');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('987654321', 'Terry', 'S', 'Duffy', '1990-06-20', '231 Berry', 'Bellaire', 'TX', '11236', 'F', '43000', '888665555', '4');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('987987987', 'Jossef', 'V', 'Goldberg', '1959-03-29', '980 Dallas', 'Houston', 'TX', '11233', 'M', '25000', '987654321', '4');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('999887777', 'Terry', 'J', 'Zelaya', '1958-07-19', '3321 Castle', 'Spring', 'TX', '11239', 'F', '25000', '987654321', '4');
INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE (SSN, FIRSTNAME, MI, LASTNAME, DOB, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SEX, SALARY, SUPERVISOR_SSN, DEPT_NO) VALUES ('999887777', 'John', '', 'Clay', '1938-07-19', '3321 Castle', 'Spring', 'TX', '11239', 'F', '35000', '987654321', '3');

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dept FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_SSN) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT fk_empdept FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_NO);

CREATE SEQUENCE dependent_seq START WITH 1;
nsert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,123456789, 'Lili','Tamburello',to_date( '1978-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'),'F','DAUGHTER');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,123456789, 'Anna','Tamburello',to_date( '1957-05-05','yyyy-mm-dd'),'F','SPOUSE');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,123456789, 'Gregory','Tamburello',to_date( '1978-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),'M','SON');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,333445555, 'Alice','Bradley',to_date( '1976-04-05','yyyy-mm-dd'),'F','DAUGHTER');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,333445555, 'Theodore','Bradley',to_date( '1973-10-25','yyyy-mm-dd'),'M','SON');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,987654321, 'Abner','Duffy',to_date( '1969-02-28','yyyy-mm-dd'),'M','SPOUSE');
Insert into DEPENDENT (DEPENDENT_NO,SSN,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DOB,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES (dependent_seq.nextval,987654321, 'Aby','John',to_date( '1970-02-28','yyyy-mm-dd'),'M','SPOUSE');

INSERT INTO DEPT_LOCATION(DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE)
SELECT DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE FROM STAGING_DEPLOCATION A
INNER JOIN LOCATION B ON B.LOCATION = A.LOCATION
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON D.DEPARTMENTNAME = A.DEPARTMENTNAME;

INSERT  INTO DEPT_LOCATION (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE) VALUES ('headquarters', 'Houston', '');
INSERT  INTO DEPT_LOCATION (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE) VALUES ('administration', 'Stafford', '');
INSERT  INTO DEPT_LOCATION (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE) VALUES ('research', 'Bellaire', '');
INSERT  INTO DEPT_LOCATION (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE) VALUES ('research', 'Houston', '');
INSERT  INTO DEPT_LOCATION (DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, ISACTIVE) VALUES ('research', 'Sugarland', '');


INSERT  INTO LOCATION (LOCATION_NO, LOCATION) VALUES ('1', 'Bellaire');
INSERT  INTO LOCATION (LOCATION_NO, LOCATION) VALUES ('2', 'Houston');
INSERT  INTO LOCATION (LOCATION_NO, LOCATION) VALUES ('3', 'Stafford');
INSERT  INTO LOCATION (LOCATION_NO, LOCATION) VALUES ('4', 'Sugarland');

INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('1', '5', '1', 'ProductX');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('2', '5', '4', 'ProductY');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('3', '5', '2', 'ProductZ');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('10', '4', '3', 'Computerization');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('20', '1', '2', 'Reorganization');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('30', '4', '3', 'Newbenefits');
INSERT  INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NO, DEPT_NO, LOCATION_NO, PROJECTNAME) VALUES ('1', '5', '1', 'ProductX');

INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('123456789', '1', '33');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('123456789', '2', '8');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('333445555', '2', '10');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('333445555', '3', '10');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('333445555', '10', '10');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('333445555', '20', '10');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('453453453', '1', '20');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('453453453', '2', '20');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('666884444', '3', '40');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('888665555', '20', '');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('987654321', '20', '15');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('987654321', '30', '20');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('987987987', '10', '35');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('987987987', '30', '5');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('999887777', '10', '10');
INSERT  INTO WORKS_ON (SSN, PROJECT_NO, HOURS) VALUES ('999887777', '30', '30');



COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is "DLSQL"?

Answer (score 1):

Because, when you are trying to `INSERT  INTO EMPLOYEE` where you have mentioned **12 columns**, but you are passing **13 values**.

You need to pass ***exactly same number of values***, which you have specific after `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE`

Comment: They both have 13 values.

Comment: @GopherTech are you sure ?? Did you counted? otherwise, you won't get that error.

Comment: @GopherTech There is no column for `'3321 Castle'` value and that seems to be address column.

Comment: Yes, I found the issue! But it still does not compile.

Comment: @GopherTech lol, i didn't downvoted. And, is it kind of agreement ? :D